# Splitting file into multiple files

Tags: macos, shell, unix, awk, split

I want to split text file into multiple text files based on line starting with number(1. *) For example I want to split this text file into 2 files:

```
 1. J Med Chem. 2013 May 23;56(10):4028-43. doi: 10.1021/jm400241j. Epub 2013 May 13.

Optimization of benzoxazole-based inhibitors of Cryptosporidium parvum inosine
5'-monophosphate dehydrogenase.

Gorla SK, Kavitha M, Zhang M, Chin JE, Liu X, Striepen B, Makowska-Grzyska M, Kim
Y, Joachimiak A, Hedstrom L, Cuny GD.

Department of Biology, Brandeis University , 415 South Street, Waltham,
Massachusetts 02454, USA.

Cryptosporidium parvum is an enteric protozoan parasite that has emerged as a
major cause of diarrhea, malnutrition, and gastroenteritis and poses a potential 
bioterrorism threat.

PMID: 23668331  [PubMed - indexed for MEDLINE]


 2.Biochem Pharmacol. 2013 May 1;85(9):1370-8. doi: 10.1016/j.bcp.2013.02.014. Epub 
2013 Feb 16.

Carbonyl reduction of triadimefon by human and rodent 11β-hydroxysteroid
dehydrogenase 1.

Meyer A, Vuorinen A, Zielinska AE, Da Cunha T, Strajhar P, Lavery GG, Schuster D,
Odermatt A.

Swiss Center for Applied Human Toxicology and Division of Molecular and Systems
Toxicology, Department of Pharmaceutical Sciences, University of Basel,
Klingelbergstrasse 50, 4056 Basel, Switzerland.

11β-Hydroxysteroid dehydrogenase 1 (11β-HSD1) catalyzes the conversion of
inactive 11-oxo glucocorticoids (endogenous cortisone, 11-dehydrocorticosterone
and synthetic prednisone) to their potent 11β-hydroxyl forms (cortisol,
corticosterone and prednisolone).

Copyright © 2013 Elsevier Inc. All rights reserved.

PMID: 23419873  [PubMed - indexed for MEDLINE]
```

I tried this:

```
awk 'NF{print > $2;close($2);}' file
```

and this:

```
split -l 2
```

but I'm confused about how to give empty lines. (I'm new to awk.)

Comment: I tried awk 'NF{print > $2;close($2);}' file and split -l 2 but confused how to give empty lines. I am new to  awk

Answer (score 3):

I THINK what you're looking for is:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+\./{ if (fname) close(fname); fname="out_"$1; sub(/\..*/,"",fname) } {print > fname}' file
```

Commented version per @zjhui's request:

```
awk '
/^[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+\./ {     # IF the line starts with spaces, then digits then a period THEN
    if (fname)                      #     IF the output file name variable is populated THEN
        close(fname)                #         close the file youve been writing to until now
                                    #     ENDIF
    fname="out_"$1                  #     set the output file name to the word "out_" followed by the first field of this line, e.g. "out_2.Biochem"
    sub(/\..*/,"",fname)            #     strip everything from the period on from the file name so it becomes e.g. "out_2"
}                                   # ENDIF
{                                   # IF true THEN
    print > fname                   #     print the current record to the filename stored in the variable fname, e.g. "out_2".
}                                   # ENDIF
' file
```

Comment: I got this error. awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /^[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+\./{ if (fname) close(fname); fname="out_"$1; >>>  sub(/\..*/,"",fname} <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
 missing )

Comment: Iadded the misisng `)`. Got to say though - I think with just the tiniest bit of thought and probably less effort than it took you to post your comment you could have fixed it yourself. The error message was pretty clear and I'm sure you've seen function calls in other languages.

Comment: it worked on my machine. And i wondered how this works? can you explain a little detail? for this statment `if (fname) close(fname); fname="out_"$1; sub(/\..*/,"",fname)` can not understand clearly.

Comment: @zjhui I added a commented version.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
awk -F"\." '/^ +[0-9]+\./
           {
            gsub(/ /,"",$1);
            file="file_"$1
           }
          {
            print >file
          }' Your_file
```

Comment: I think you need the pattern and at least the open brace on the same line.  As it stands, you detect the numbers and print the line; each line messes with the file name; and you print to file.